# C# Global Page Variable

Tags: c#, mysql, variables, web-config, global

I'm aware of how to do this in PHP, but I'm only now getting back into C# so please forgive me.

Basically, I have two variables - name and email, that need to be set somewhere universally accessible across pages within the same folder. Obviously one solution is to store them in a MySQL database, but in this situation I'd only have one field for a table. That seems... Stupid. Accessing that field and connecting to the database unnecessarily seems, well, superfluous as I'm sure there's another, better, way to do this.

Can you change web.config variables from within the confines of C# without write support to the web.config? Is there another way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at the [`Global.asax` file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1xaas8a2%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). You can add session- and application-wide variables to members of this object.

Comment: How would you do this without visual-studio though? Is there special linkage that needs to be done in the web.config or elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot change web.config variables without being able to change the web.config file. This is a bad idea anyway as changes to web.config will cause your web application to restart.

There are some options for keeping information at various scope levels.

1. Store the information in the Session (See [HttpContext.Session Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.session.aspx), [HttpSessionState.Item Property (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8dhkksh8.aspx), [Page.Session Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.session.aspx)). Such items are per user and are persistent for the duration of that users session.
2. Store the information in the Cache. (See [Cache Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache)) Such items are persistent for the life of the application.
3. Create a base class from which your pages inherit and add properties to the base class.